# Replace a character not followed by the same character

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

**Replace a character not followed by the same character using JavaScript.**

I have a string where the string may contain a forward slash( / ).
If the string contains a single forward slash then I need to replace it with two '/' so that it becomes escaped.

e.g. `'sample/word'` needs to become `'sample//word'`

Another rule is an odd number of slashes needs to become an even number.

e.g `'///'` => `'////'`

I have looked into using regex but as I understand the negative lookbehind that is required is not available in JavaScript ES6. Any help appreciated!

Sample strings I have been working with:

```
let strs = [
  'sample/single',
  'sample//double',
  'sample',
  '//',
  '/',
  '//sample',
  'sample//',
  '/sample',
  'sample/',
  'sample///',
  '///sample',
  '////sample',
  '/////sample',
  'sample/////',
  'sample////',
  'sample / again',
  'sa/mple agai/n'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let strs = [
  'sample/single',
  'sample//double',
  'sample',
  '//',
  '/',
  '//sample',
  'sample//',
  '/sample',
  'sample/',
  'sample///',
  '///sample',
  '////sample',
  '/////sample',
  'sample/////',
  'sample////',
  'sample / again',
  'sa/mple agai/n'
];

const slashMeUpBro = (word) => {
    let words = word.split('//');
    word.split('//').forEach((word, index) => words[index] = word.replace(/\/+/g, '//'));
    return words.join('//');
}

strs.forEach(word => console.log(slashMeUpBro(word)));
```

Comment: Nice use of split and replace. I'll look into a comparison between your solution vs Nick's solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using your rules from above you can use the following function to satisfy them and achieve your output. Here I have passed a function into the `replace` function, which allows you to check if the regular expression matched an odd or even amount of `/` and thus replace accordingly:

```js
let strs = [
  'sample/single',
  'sample//double',
  'sample',
  '//',
  '/',
  '//sample',
  'sample//',
  '/sample',
  'sample/',
  'sample///',
  '///sample',
  '////sample',
  '/////sample',
  'sample/////',
  'sample////',
  'sample / again',
  'sa/mple agai/n'
];

let result = 
strs.map(elem => elem.replace(/\/+/g, match => match.length % 2 != 0 ? match+'/':match));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if / characters in row as its calculate total / in text, work for your data set except last one, this may helpful you for some extent.

```
var newstr = str;
if( str.match(/([/])/g).length % 2 == 1 )
   newstr = str.replace(/([/])/g, "$1$1");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to handle any that aren't in a row. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex, you could use:

`(^|[^\/])(\/)(?=(?:\/\/)*(?!\/))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qw2SqM/1)

**Explanation**

- `(^|[^\/])` First capturing group to assert the start of the line or match not a forward slash
- `(\/)` Second capturing group match a forward slash
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:\/\/)*` Repeat zero or more times `//`
  - `(?!\/)` Negative lookahead to assert that what follows is not a forward slash
- `)` Close positive lookahead

Replace with the 2 capturing groups followed by a forward slash

`$1$2/`

```js
let pattern = /(^|[^\/])(\/)(?=(?:\/\/)*(?!\/))/g;
let strs = [
  '//\n/',
  'sample/single',
  'sample//double',
  'sample',
  '//',
  '/',
  '//sample',
  'sample//',
  '/sample',
  'sample/',
  'sample///',
  '///sample',
  '////sample',
  '/////sample',
  'sample/////',
  'sample////',
  'sample / again',
  'sa/mple agai/n'
];

strs.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.replace(pattern, "$1$2/"))
});
```